# How exactly work the @OneToMany JPA annotation in this example? Is it related to a table column or an entity class field?

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0, one-to-many, joincolumn

I have 2 DB tables named respectivelly **T_ACCOUNT** and **T_ACCOUNT_BENEFICIARY**.

These tables have the following structure:

```
create table T_ACCOUNT (ID integer identity primary key, NUMBER varchar(9), NAME varchar(50) not null, CREDIT_CARD varchar(16), unique(NUMBER));

create table T_ACCOUNT_BENEFICIARY (ID integer identity primary key, ACCOUNT_ID integer, NAME varchar(50), ALLOCATION_PERCENTAGE decimal(5,2) not null, SAVINGS decimal(8,2) not null, unique(ACCOUNT_ID, NAME));
```

And the **T_ACCOUNT** table is bound to the **T_ACCOUNT_BENEFICIARY** table with a one to many relationship, this is the graphical representation:

[image]

So this is the first class named **Account** that map the **T_ACCOUNT** table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="T_ACCOUNT")
public class Account {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long entityId;

    @Column(name="NUMBER")
    private String number;

    @Column(name="NAME")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="ACCOUNT_ID")
    private Set<Beneficiary> beneficiaries = new HashSet<Beneficiary>();

    @Column(name="CREDIT_CARD")
    private String creditCardNumber;

    // GETTERS & SETTERS
}
```

And this is the **Beneficiary** class that map the **T_ACCOUNT_BENEFICIARY** table:

```
/**
 * A single beneficiary allocated to an account. Each beneficiary has a name (e.g. Annabelle) and a savings balance
 * tracking how much money has been saved for he or she to date (e.g. $1000).
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="T_ACCOUNT_BENEFICIARY")
public class Beneficiary {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="ID")
    private Long entityId;

    @Column(name="NAME")
    private String name;

    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverride(name="value",column=@Column(name="ALLOCATION_PERCENTAGE"))
    private Percentage allocationPercentage;

    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverride(name="value",column=@Column(name="SAVINGS"))
    private MonetaryAmount savings = MonetaryAmount.zero();
```

As you can see into the **Account** I have the **beneficiaries** field that implement the **one to may** relationship

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name="ACCOUNT_ID")
private Set<Beneficiary> beneficiaries = new HashSet<Beneficiary>();
```

I know that, on the DB, this relationship is implemented by the **ACCOUNT_ID** field of the **T_ACCOUNT_BENEFICIARY** table (so multiple row of the **T_ACCOUNT_BENEFICIARY** table can have the same value of the **ACCOUNT_ID** field and this means that a single row of the **T_ACCOUNT** table can be associated to more than one rows of **T_ACCOUNT_BENEFICIARY** table).

As you can see in the previous sippet there is the **@JoinColumn(name="ACCOUNT_ID")** annotation.

My doubt is generated by the fact that I have an **ACCOUNT_ID** column on my **T_ACCOUNT_BENEFICIARY** table, infact:

```
create table T_ACCOUNT_BENEFICIARY (ID integer identity primary key, ACCOUNT_ID integer, NAME varchar(50), ALLOCATION_PERCENTAGE decimal(5,2) not null, SAVINGS decimal(8,2) not null, unique(ACCOUNT_ID, NAME));
```

but this column seems to not be mapped on the **Beneficiary** that map this **T_ACCOUNT_BENEFICIARY** table.

So my doubts is: the **@JoinColumn(name="ACCOUNT_ID")** is working at relational level performing the join operation on the **ACCOUNT_ID** column of the table mapped by the **Beneficiary** entity (**T_ACCOUNT_BENEFICIARY**) or am I missing something? How exactly is performed this join?

If my interpretation is right can I work at entity level and say to join the **beneficiaries** field of my **Account** entity class to a new **accountId** field inserted into my **Beneficiary** entity class and mapping the **ACCOUNT_ID** column of the **T_ACCOUNT_BENEFICIARY** table?

Tnx

Comment: JoinColumn should be used on ManyToOne and this will be your owner side, and the inverse side will have OneToMany with mappedBy attribute.

Answer (score 1):

It seems is a [Unidirectional OneToMany](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany#Unidirectional_OneToMany.2C_No_Inverse_ManyToOne.2C_No_Join_Table_.28JPA_2.0_ONLY.29) relationship

In JPA 2.0 a `@JoinColumn` can be used on a OneToMany to define the foreign key

Comment: Ok but when I writ @JoinColumn(name="ACCOUNT_ID") the meaning is that ACCOUNT_ID is refered to the column name of the T_ACCOUNT_BENEFICIARY table and not to a field of the entity class that map this table (that can not exist)?

Comment: Yes. `ACCOUNT_ID` refers to the actual Database column on `T_ACCOUNT_BENEFICIARY`. See the example on the link where the table `Phone` has a column `OWNER_ID` and the class `Employee` uses `@JoinColumn(name="OWNER_ID", referencedColumnName="EMP_ID")` for the `List<Phone> phones`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question. But what you have done with your @JoinColumn annotation is correct and Hibernate will execute appropriate SQL statements when you have multiple beneficiaries for your account. For example executing multiple INSERTS if you have two Beneficiaries for an Account. And yes using the @JoinColumn annotation is at the hibernate level. If you want to access an Account from a Beneficiary entity you would need to define a Bidirectional relationship in the Beneficiary class like below.

```
@Entity
@Table("T_ACCOUNT_BENEFICIARY")
public class Beneficiary {
 @ManyToOne(mappedBy = "beneficiaries")
 Account account;
 ...
}
```

Comment: my question was another, I was asking if doing @JoinColumn(name="ACCOUNT_ID") Hibernate perform the join between the 2 tables (T_ACCOUNT and T_ACCOUNT_BENEFICIARY) using the ID column  of the T_ACCOUNT table and the ACCOUNT_ID column of the T_ACCOUNT_BENEFICIARY table. Is it or is it not?

Comment: Yes it will perform the join but you also need to tell hibernate what sort of join relationship it is. And in your case it is one to many and you do it exactly like you have done in your Account class by using @OneToMany annotation. Hope it helps. Cheers.